# javascript- webrtc displaying local ip on textbox instead <li></li>

Tags: javascript

How would I go about displaying the result on a html textbox instead of

```
getIPs(function(ip){
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = ip;
            //local IPs
            if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
            //IPv6 addresses
            else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);
            //assume the rest are public IPs
            else
                document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use the bellow logic

```
var text = ip;
        //local IPs
        if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
            document.getElementById("textBox1").value = document.getElementById("textBox1").value + text;
        //IPv6 addresses
        else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
            document.getElementById("textBox2").value = document.getElementById("textBox2").value + text;
        //assume the rest are public IPs
        else
            document.getElementById("textBox3").value = document.getElementById("textBox3").value + text;
```